# How to return cell value if no dot exist instead of return "#VALUE" in Google Sheet / Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

This formula do the job, but I do not want it to return #VALUE!, instead of the name if no dot exist end of string.

Also

"*Dr. Mrs Zainab Adams.*" -> "*Dr Mrs Zainab Adams.*" I would like to return "***Dr. Mrs Zainab Adams***" in this case

```
=LEFT(G2, SEARCH(".",G2) - 1) & RIGHT(G2, LEN(G2) - SEARCH(".", G2))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wrap in `=IFERROR(LEFT(G2, SEARCH(".",G2) - 1) & RIGHT(G2, LEN(G2) - SEARCH(".", G2)),G2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=PROPER(IF(RIGHT(F2,1)=".",LEFT(F2,LEN(F2)-1),F2))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).